# fill url parameter value based on form input

Tags: html, forms, url, input, parameters

I have a URL looks like this

```
  site.com/dir/?id=xxx
```

is it possible to create an HTML form that allows the user to enter the value of id and opens the page in other tab?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basic HTML code to do it :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<body>
<h1>The input element</h1>
<form action="https://www.google.com/dir/" target="_blank">
    <label for="id">Enter value of ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="id"><br><be>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>Click the "Submit" button to open page in new tab.</p>
</body>
</html>
```